# What is the recommended way to implement `withdraw` to a Gnosis Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I recently implemented a `withdraw` function from my smart contract to a Gnosis Safe address, and I ran into many problems because the Tx was failing due to out of gas.

After many research I finally [found out why](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe).

But even with this solution, it was still a challenge to get the funds out of my contract.

So my question is, what is the recommended way to implement `withdraw` to a Gnosis Safe address? Is there a way to bypass this problem or is it uncircumventable?

**UPDATE 1**

This was my "faulty" implementation:

```js
  function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
    payable(vault).transfer(address(this).balance);
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Very good information [here](https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/).

Thanks @mikheevm

Comment: You should have the `payable` keyword `function withdraw() external payable onlyOwner`

Comment: https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

Comment: @mikheevm if you post an answer I'll accept it. Everything I needed to know is inside that article. Thanks !